# CUDA compare arrays

Tags: c#, cuda, cuda.net

Trying to make an app that will compare 1-to-multiple bitmaps. there is one reference bitmap and multiple other bitmaps. Result from each compare should be new bitmap with diffs. Maybe comparing bitmaps rather as textures than arrays? My biggest problem is making kernel accept more than one input pointer, and how to compare the data..

```
extern "C" __global__ void compare(float *odata, float *idata, int width, int height)
```

works and following does not (i call the function with enough params)

```
extern "C" __global__ void compare(float *odata, float *idata, float *idata2, int width, int height)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it does not work?  Is there a compiler error?

Answer (score 1):

Your function prototypes are OK.  The problem lies elsewhere.  In general, make sure that you are properly allocating device memory for all input and output arrays, and make sure that you're correctly copying data to and from your device arrays.